# Yii2, сложная таблица. Объединение ячеек, сумма значений и экспорт таблицы

Tags: php, yii2, gridview, kartik

Есть данные, которые необходимо вывести в таблицу на странице, а затем добавить кнопку экспорта этой таблицы в excel. Предполагается, что с помощью kartik-v/yii2-export с указанием этих Providers и Columns использованных при выводе данных на страницу, я смогу без проблем экспортировать таблицу.

**Суть проблемы**: не могу правильно описать Columns для GridView, чтобы получилась именно такая таблица.

**Итоговая таблица** должна выглядеть так:

[image: Итоговая таблица]

1. Одинаковые значения домов объединяются.
2. У каждой строки (квартира №1, №2, №3, №4) есть подстроки. 1 или более. Каждую эту строку необходимо вывести объединив ячейки (квартира, фамилия, имя) куда впишется инфа.
3. У каждой строки есть сумма значений подстрок (долг по квартире = сумма долгов сожителей в ней)
4. Есть сумма в шапке всех долгов.

На данный момент есть такой код. Общая сумма долга не просчитана, ячейки "сожителей" не объеденены:

1. $provider - в данный момент массив всех строк (вместе с сожителями, т.е. 10 строк по скриншоту):

```
$provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
  'allModels' => $data,
  'pagination' => false
]);
```

2. $columns:

```
$columns = [
  [
    'header' => 'Дом',
    'attribute' => 'home',
    'group' => true, //объединяет строки одинаковых домов
  ],
  [
    'header' => 'Квартира',
    'value' => function($model) {
      return isset($model['rm_name']) ? $model['rm_name'] : $model['apartment']; //позволяет понять какая это строка - общая или подстрока (сожитель)
    },
    /*'contentOptions' => function ($model) { //работает, объединяет ячейки, но kartik-v/yii2-export не хочет работать с анонимной функцией у contentOptions, а так же следующие выводимые ячейки "Фамилия" и "Имя" ломают таблицу
        return isset($model['rm_name']) ? ['colspan' => 3] : [];
    },*/
  ],
  [
    'header' => 'Фамилия',
    'value' => function($model) {
       return isset($model['rm_name']) ? '' : $model['cname'];
    },
  ],
  [
    'header' => 'Имя',
    'value' => function($model) {
      return isset($model['rm_name']) ? '' : $model['cname'];
    },
  ],
  [
    'header' => 'Долг',
    'attribute' => 'rate',
    //groupFooter => content => GridView::F_SUM не верно суммирует долги, поскольку он суммирует значения и сожителей, которые уже учтены в сумме по квартире.
  ],
];
```

3. Вывод на страницу:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $provider,
  'columns' => $columns,
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providers и Columns в большей степени предназначены для обработки простых таблиц. Когда дело доходит до сложностей с объединением колонок, начинается извращение. И спрашивается, оно надо? kartik-v/yii2-export не панацея и если с помощью него надо экспортнуть такую сложную таблицу, то костылей там будет целая куча. Пока ощущается, что такая жертва только ради использования этого модуля. Но никто не запрещает же сделать самому именно под эту задачу (вероятно это будет быстрее и проще). И никаких рамок и ограничений от использования стороннего пакета.

**Первое** - использовать паттерн компоновщик (Composite). Это позволит довольно просто подсчитать задолженность по квартире, по дому и итоговую.  https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/composite

**Второе** - обработку вынести в сервис и собрать "правильный" массив объектов, чтобы его можно было использовать в экшене для отрисовки на фронте и в экшене для экспорта.

**Третье** - экспорт данных в файл сделать на основе паттерна Шаблонный метод (Template method). Алгоритм получения данных, названия файла и наполнение одинаковый и описывается в основном (абстрактном) классе. А реализация (расширение файла, формат) у каждого своя и в отдельном классе. Например для pdf, html и т.д. https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/template-method

Опишу только компоновщик, потому что шаблонный метод довольно простой и популярный. В примере по ссылке очень понятно.

Создаем компонент, от которого унаследуем класс жильца, квартиры, дома и жилого комплекса

```
abstract class Component
{
    protected $parent;

    public function setParent(Component $parent): void
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function getParent(): Component
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function add(Component $component): void
    {
    }

    public function remove(Component $component): void
    {
    }

    public function isComposite(): bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    abstract public function operation(): int;
}
```

Создаем класс жильца, в котором есть поле с суммой долга и метод, который возвращает сумму долга.

```
class Resident extends Component
{
    private $amount;

    public function __construct(int $amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public function operation(): int
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }
}
```

Далее создаем класс самого компоновщика, который уже будет формировать дерево должников из жильцов, квартир и домов.

```
class Composite extends Component
{
    protected $children;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new \SplObjectStorage();
    }

    public function add(Component $component): void
    {
        $this->children->attach($component);
        $component->setParent($this);
    }

    public function remove(Component $component): void
    {
        $this->children->detach($component);
        $component->setParent(null);
    }

    public function isComposite(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function operation(): int
    {
        $results = 0;
        foreach ($this->children as $child) {
            $results += $child->operation();
        }

        return $results;
    }
}
```

Теперь собираем массив жильцов, домов и смотрим, кто чего должен.

```
// функция будет принимать объект и возвращать сумму долга в независимости от того житель это или целый дом
function getAmount(Component $component)
{
    echo "Amount: " . $component->operation();
}

// один житель и сумма его долга
$resident = new Resident(100);
echo "Resident debt:\n";
getAmount($resident);
echo "\n\n";

// несколько жителей и сумма долга по всему дому
$residents = [new Resident(150), new Resident(200), new Resident(200)];

$house1 = new Composite();
foreach ($residents as $item) {
    $house1->add($item);
}

echo "House1 debt:\n";
getAmount($house1);
echo "\n\n";

// тоже самое по другому дому
$residents = [new Resident(300), new Resident(350), new Resident(100)];

$house2 = new Composite();
foreach ($residents as $item) {
    $house2->add($item);
}
echo "House2 debt:\n";
getAmount($house2);
echo "\n\n";


// все должники и общая сумма долга по жилому комплексу
$debtors = [$house1, $house2, $resident];

$complex = new Composite();
foreach ($debtors as $item) {
    $complex->add($item);
}
echo "Complex debt:\n";
getAmount($complex);
echo "\n\n";
```

PS: Этим ответом я хотел показать, что не всегда есть смысл использовать готовые решения, которые не подходят для задачи. Довольно часто можно быстрее написать что-то свое с возможностью масштабирования, чем мучаться с костылями и "готовым" решением, загоняя себя в рамки.

Comment: Спасибо. Сделать свою реализацию не проблема, просто я думал, что инструменты достаточно гибкие, чтобы вывести любую таблицу. Значит сделаем по своему.

Comment: В некоторой степени они гибкие, но все равно есть предел этой гибкости. Надо стараться применять паттерны, кто бы что ни говорил. Экономит кучу времени.